# iOS 7 - navigation bar item text color

Tags: ios, ios7, uipopovercontroller, uinavigationitem, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm having an issue with text color of navigation bar item on iOS7.

All things are fine until I present a viewcontroller, from this time, all navigation bar items  text color are Grey. Do you have any experience with this issue?

The codes used to present VC:

```
[passcodePopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2 ,currentWindow.frame.size.height/2,1,1)
                                     inView:currentWindow
                   permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:NO];[passcodePopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2 ,currentWindow.frame.size.height/2,1,1)
                                     inView:currentWindow
                   permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:NO];
```

Comment: I found the root cause, when present a viewcontroller, will change tint attribute of the app. dont know why

Answer (score 1):

```
//call the below code in ViewDidLoad /It works fine in iOS7

UILabel *navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 100)];
navLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
navLabel.text = @"Event Details";
navLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -2);
[navLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
navLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView = navLabel;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] ;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0]; // font size
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

label.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; // change this color
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Product Info.", @""); // lable name
[label sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],
   NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[UIColor whiteColor],
   NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)],
   NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:0.0],
   NSFontAttributeName,nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the passcodePopover's viewdidLoad method you will want to use this code.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];
```

If you don't have a navigationController in your popover you will have to change the code slightly, also you may not want to use [UIColor whiteColor]. Instead substitute your own choice of color.

Answer (score 0):

use below code in viewdid Load function

```
  if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {

        // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
         [[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:NavigationColor];
    } else
     {
         [[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; // it set color of bar button item text 
    }
```

Comment: The technique to use for checking operating system version depends on your target platform, as follows:
To check the version of iOS at run time, use code like this:
`NSString *osVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];`
To check the version of OS X at run time, use the Gestalt function and the System Version Selectors constants.

Answer (score 0):

create a category instead:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (custom)
- (void)setCustomNavigationBar: (NSString *)_strTitle
{
    [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UILabel *_lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
    _lblTitle.text = _strTitle;
    _lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [_lblTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kAppFontBold size:kAppFontBoldSize]];
    [_lblTitle setTextColor:[UIColor navigationBarColor]];
    [[self topItem] setTitleView:_lblTitle];
}
```

Where `kAppFontBold` and `kAppFontBoldSize` are macros.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. It may help you.. Here I've set `font and text color` for two states.

```
[barItemForIndex setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                    [UIFont systemFontOfSize:Tabbar_Item_Font_Size], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                    [UIColor darkGrayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                    nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[barItemForIndex setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                    [UIFont systemFontOfSize:Tabbar_Item_Font_Size], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                    [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                    nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

**Note :** `setTitleTextAttributes:` method only available ios5.0+.